# Launch external process associated with a file and send this application to the back

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I've seen loads of code to launch an external application via a file, but that's not the problem. To clarify exactly the behaviour I want:

1. For a given filename, launch the correct process.
2. If there is no associated process, the proper shell dialog should prompt the user to associate one.
3. While the application is launched, this application needs to go to the back of the Z-order (or just behind the app that is launching) and STAY THERE.

Step 3 is what I haven't got right. I am launching Photoshop via a psd file, but while the aplash screen is shown, it flashes as my app fights for the focus. Once it starts up properly, all is well, but I don't like the flickering while the flash screen is displayed.

Here is my best attempt so far:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Romy.Core
{
    internal static class Example
    {
        public const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

        private static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

        private const uint SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;

        private const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;

        private const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;

        public static void SendWindowBack(IntPtr handle)
        {
            NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        }

        public static async void ShellExecuteFile(this IWin32Window window, string filename)
        {
            var p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = filename,
                Verb = "open",
                UseShellExecute = true,
                ErrorDialog = true
            });

            SendWindowBack(window.Handle);

            try
            {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        p.WaitForInputIdle();
                        IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;

                        while (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250D));
                            handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
                        }

                        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            if (NativeMethods.IsIconic(handle))
                                NativeMethods.ShowWindowAsync(handle, SW_RESTORE);

                            if (NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(handle))
                                NativeMethods.SetActiveWindow(handle);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
                    catch (PlatformNotSupportedException) { }
                    catch (NotSupportedException) { }
                    catch (Exception ex) { ex.Log(); }
                }).TimeoutAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3D));
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }

        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        internal static class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            internal static extern bool IsIconic(System.IntPtr hWnd);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            internal static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(System.IntPtr hWnd);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            internal static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
                int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            internal static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(System.IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            internal static extern System.IntPtr SetActiveWindow(System.IntPtr hWnd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not related to your issue, but you should almost never use `async void`.

Comment: Except for fire and forget. Please don't make unrelated nonsensical comments. Oh sorry... I didn't see the "almost".

Comment: @JeromeViveiros except for fire and forget *events*. In any other case it's an error. In any case the question has nothing to do with asynchronous execution

Comment: Event handlers anyone... Fire and forget methods and events are not necessarily the same thing. Otherwise +1 for repeating my comment immediately after it. Maybe I should edit the code in my question to avoid further irrelevant comments? I did use an async task simply to be able to wait asynchronously for the process to start inside of my method. This method is fire and forget (I am not interested in waiting for the process after it has launched) but I am really not interested in discussing the merits of async void.

Comment: @Panagiotis I just realized the tone of my comment may be offensive. That was not my intention. You are correct that the code in the question, while it happens to be async, has nothing to do with async execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your call to **SendWindowBack** and replace **SetForegroundWindow** with [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This should meet your requierment:

> ...(or just behind the app that is launching) and STAY THERE..

```
const int GWL_HWNDPARENT = (-8);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr childHandle, int nIndex, IntPtr parentHandle);

if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    if (NativeMethods.IsIconic(handle))
        NativeMethods.ShowWindowAsync(handle, SW_RESTORE);

    SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_HWNDPARENT, window.Handle)
    NativeMethods.SetActiveWindow(handle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's been so long, I forgot I asked the question. Will check it out when I get the time.